# Join Tool (Data Management)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins

I have a new table with statistics data that has been calculated with the tool: Zonal Statistics as a Table; in order to know the min, max, mean, range, std, etc, from a thickness value that was previously calculated. My new table with this statistics data, has a field called ObjectID which is also in another old table, I want to relate this new statistic data with this old table in order to have all the information of each objectID (within both tables) in just one table. I am trying to use the Join tool, in order to do this, but maybe because there are almost 3000 ObjectID in these input table the computer keeps getting stack, I have also tried with the add join tool but it also doesn't work, what can I do?

Comment: You can try to set the join with few record to understand if it works correctly, then you can decide to go on with that idea or try another one

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are large I would suggest importing them into a file geodatabase before joining, this will enhance performance.  The big gotcha with joins is making sure the joining field data types are the same between the two tables (e.g. numeric to numeric OR text to text NOT numeric to text OR text to numeric).